# Number of ways for 7 people to be seated so that two particular ones are separated by 3

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> 7 boys are to be seated in a row. Calculate the number of different ways in which this can be done if 2 particular boys, X and Y, have exactly 3 other boys between them.

I have posted an image of my solution can someone explain where am I going wrong. I have divided the question into three parts.

[image]

Comment: As currently stated your question shows no effort on your part, and this puts off most people here. Could you please tell us how you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: @A.P. I have posted an image of my solution can someone explain where am I going wrong? I have divided the question into three parts.

Comment: You forgot to take into account that there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways of selecting the boys between boys $A$ and $B$.  Since there are $3!$ ways of arranging the three boys who sit between $A$ and $B$, the number of ways of arranging the boys who sit between $A$ and $B$ is $$\binom{5}{3} \cdot 3! = 10 \cdot 6 = 60$$ rather than $3! = 6$.  That is why your answer is off by a factor of $10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider X,Y and the three boys as a single boy. That reduces the system into $3$ boys and can be seated in $3!$ ways.

Now, you can choose the middle $3$ boys in $^5P_3$ ways and $X,Y$ can interchange positions in $2!$ ways.

Carry out the calculations using this and the rule of product.

Can you continue?

Comment: $^nP_r=\dfrac{n!}{r!}$ is the number of ways $r$ distinct objects can be permuted out of $n$ distinct objects at once (where order of arrangement is taken into account).

Comment: @Hamza750, if my solution helped you, be sure to upvote it. ;)

Comment: Why are we including X and Y to the group?

Answer (score 1):

So we first glue five (empty) seats together, the first and the last seats will be $X,Y$'s, to which we can have $7-5+1$ combinations/settings, then for each setting we have $2$ options for $X,Y$ and $5!$ options for the other $5$ people, hence the answer is $(7-5+1)2\cdot 5!=720$.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your argument could be clarified.  You have three ways of positioning the block of five (left, right, or middle), two ways of placing the boys at either end of the block, and $5!$ ways of arranging the remaining boys.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig which part of my answer is not clear?

Comment: The part I found unclear was what you meant by combinations/settings.  Also, you may want to explain that $7 - 5 + 1$ represents the number of places where the block can begin.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sorry for causing any confusion, actually I just intended to let them to take seat at the final moment, before that just set some constraint on the seating plan

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 ways with X _ _ _ Y in that order.

1. X _ _ _ Y_ _   = 5P3 * 2P2       = 60*2 = 120
2. _ X _ _ _ Y _  = 5P3 * 2P2 * 1P1 = 2 * 60 = 120
3. _ _ X _ _ _ Y  = 5P3 * 2P2       = 60 * 2  = 120

Total 360 combinations with X followed by Y. Similarly 360 combinations for Y followed by X

Hence answer is 360 + 360 = 720

Answer (score -1):

There are $~5~$ boys that are can be placed without restrictions hence $~5!~$.

The two boys by themselves can be arranged in two ways hence $~2!~$.

If the spaces between the five boys are considered, there are three places for the two boys to possibly be in hence $~3~$

Therefore the answer is:
$$5!~\times~2!~\times~3 = 720$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.